# C++ Optimizer : division

Tags: c++, optimization, division

Lets say I have 2 `if` statements:

```
if (frequency1_mhz > frequency2_hz * 1000) {// some code}

if (frequency1_mhz / 1000 > frequency2_hz ) {// some code}
```

I'd imagine the two to function the exact same, yet I'm guessing the first statement with the multiplication is more efficient than the division.

Would a C++ compiler optimize this? Or is this something I should take into account when designing my code

Comment: What are types of `frequency1_mhz` and `frequency2_hz`?

Comment: [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) is useful to check how code are compiled.

Comment: Read the reference manual on your compiler to find out. Usually this sort of thing depends on the level of optimization you apply to your program when compiling, which can be changed with a command-line argument.

Comment: Floats are unpredictable, so if those are floats, it's safest to assume the compiler will probably do little or no optimizations.  If they're integers, then those two statements obviously don't function the same.

Comment: There is only one answer to this question. Measure before you optimize. its never been a Hotspot of anyones program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

1. The code is not identical:

- due to rounding, there can be differences in results (e.g. `frequency1_mhz=1001` and `frequency2_hz=1`)
- the first version might overflow sooner than the second one. e.g. a `frequency2_hz` of 1000000000 would overflow an `int` (and cause UB)

2. It's still possible to perform division using multiplication.

When unsure, just look at the generated assembly.

[Here's](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/56rKcs) the generated assembly for both versions. The second one is longer, but still contains no division.

```
version1(int, int):
        imul    esi, esi, 1000
        xor     eax, eax
        cmp     esi, edi
        setl    al
        ret
version2(int, int):
        movsx   rax, edi
        imul    rax, rax, 274877907     ; look ma, no idiv!
        sar     edi, 31
        sar     rax, 38
        sub     eax, edi
        cmp     eax, esi
        setg    al
        movzx   eax, al
        ret
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my incorrect assumption, and also providing me the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

No, these are not equivalent statemets because division is not a precise inverse of multiplication for floats nor integers.

- Integer divison rounds down positive fractionns

```cpp
int f1=999;
int f2=0;

static_assert(f1>f2*1000);

static_assert(f1/1000==f2);
```

- Reciprocals are not precise:

```cpp
static_assert(10.0!=10*(1.0/10));
```

Comment: I think this answer might be clearer if instead of code, you just wrote out what the results were, so we could see the differences here.

Comment: Preferably both with integers and floats.

Answer (score 0):

If they are floats built with `-O3`, GCC will generate the same assembly (for better or for worse).

```
bool first(float frequency1_mhz,float frequency2_hz) {
    return frequency1_mhz > frequency2_hz * 1000;
}

bool second(float frequency1_mhz,float frequency2_hz) {
    return frequency1_mhz / 1000 > frequency2_hz;
}
```

[The assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/x7jKc8)

```
first(float, float):
        mulss   xmm1, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        comiss  xmm0, xmm1
        seta    al
        ret
second(float, float):
        divss   xmm0, DWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        comiss  xmm0, xmm1
        seta    al
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1148846080
```

So, really, its ends up the same code :-)